# Factorisation of a polynomial $P(x)=x^4+5x^3+5x^2-4x-3$

Tags: polynomials

One of the roots, $x=-3$ gives:

$P(x)=(x+3)(x^3+2x^2-x-1)$

$A(x)=x^3+2x^2-x-1$

How to factorize polynomial $A(x)$ (if possible)?

Comment: If $x<0$, then not necessarily $A(x)<0$. E.g., $A(-1)=1>0$. Also $2,3$ contradict each other.

Comment: what are you trying to conclude by writing $1,2,3$?

Comment: you will need the formual of Cardano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve the cubic equation using WolframAlpha and this is what I got:
[image]

So these are the roots. 
In case you want the exact fractional forms of the roots, they are as follows:
[image]

The roots are very complicated as you can see. So if you want to factorise $P(x)$, it will be $$P(x)=(x-3)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are the 3 roots of the above cubic equation $A(x)$.